# Can we write a cloud function that can be used to check if a mobile number exists for the user trying to sign in in firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

When he is trying to login via OTP. If he exists then we should send him an OTP otherwise he should first register? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

When you're interacting with the Firebase Authentication services in Cloud Functions, you're using The [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) for Node.js. This has a [`getUserByPhoneNumber` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#get-user-byphone-number), which allows you to find a user by their phone number.

Comment: Is there any method in flutter?

Comment: No there isn't, as that would be a privacy concern. And you specifically asked "Can we write a **cloud function** that can be used to check if a mobile number exists for the user trying to sign in in firebase?" :-/

Comment: So how can I achieve the following task:
When a user tries to login into the app using OTP he should land to the homepage if he is an already registered user if not then he should land at the registeration page?

Comment: You seem to have most of the parts for one option in your question: you can create a Cloud Function that checks Firebase Authentication with the Admin SDK. Another option would be to write the phone numbers to a database when the user registers, and then check against that database when the user enters their phone number.